# how to plot a graph means over time?

Tags: r, plot, graph

I have 6 treatment groups (Control, pH7, pH8, pH9, pH10, pH11) from 6 different samples (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) & measure variable - od

```
`data.frame':   288 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ od    : num  0.086 0.086 0.085 0.086 0.093 0.087 0.087 0.087 0.089 0.094 ...
 $ sample: Factor w/ 6 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ medium: Factor w/ 6 levels "Control","pH10",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 4 4 ...
```

I would like x axis to represent all the treatment groups & the dots on the graph pH means of each sample
How could I produce a graph similar to this one:

[image: example]

Sample data.

```r
 structure(list(od = c(0.086, 0.086, 0.085, 0.086, 0.093, 0.087, 0.087, 0.087, 0.089, 0.094, 0.087, 0.088, 0.09, 0.088, 0.087, 0.088, 0.086, 0.087, 0.095, 0.096), sample = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L ), medium = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("Control", "pH10", "pH11", "pH7", "pH8", "pH9"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You did certainly provide sample data, but not in a way that is easy for us to use. Please provide it using either `data.frame(...)` or `dput(head(x,n=10))` so that we can actually use it in code.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of you data using `dput(your_data[1:20,])`. Looks like you want `ggplot2` http://r-statistics.co/Complete-Ggplot2-Tutorial-Part1-With-R-Code.html

Comment: Sorry & here you go:

structure(list(od = c(0.086, 0.086, 0.085, 0.086, 0.093, 0.087, 
0.087, 0.087, 0.089, 0.094, 0.087, 0.088, 0.09, 0.088, 0.087, 
0.088, 0.086, 0.087, 0.095, 0.096), sample = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), medium = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("Control", 
"pH10", "pH11", "pH7", "pH8", "pH9"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Comments are not the right place for significant data/code. Also, because they can sometimes be hidden or missed by follow-on readers, it is almost always better to add data like that into the question itself. I've edited it in for you, please keep that in mind for your next question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

OK this is probably not quite right yet but I'll post it as and answer to be edited based on more info (little tricky without the complete data and just a photo!).

Looks like (in the photo) you have a data point per 'sample' that must be the mean of the 'od' for that 'medium' (treatment) for that 'sample' (day?)?

So I summarised the data to give me the means of each treatment group for each sample day:

```
#if you do not have the following packages then install.packages("tidyverse")
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

### REPLACE 'df' below with your dataframe name
df_summary <- df %>% 
  group_by(sample, medium) %>% 
  summarise(od_mean = mean(od))
head(df_summary)
```

Now I plot that with `mean_od` as the value on y, `sample` on x and separate them by `medium` with `colour = medium`:

```
plot <- ggplot(df_summary, aes(x = sample, y = od_mean, colour = medium))+
  geom_point()+ #add points to the plot
  geom_smooth()+ #add a smoother
  xlab("Day")+ #change axis lables
  ylab("Bacterial Density")
plot
```

Let me know if this is approaching what you need.